# linked list: how to return the whole linked list after insterting

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I am trying to return the head of a linked list in the function Insert of the following program. However, it is failing with compilation error. 
Can anyone please tell me what wrong I have done:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct ListNode
{
    int data;
    struct ListNode *next;
};


int ListLength(struct ListNode *head)
{
    int count = 0;
    struct ListNode *temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        count++;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return count;
}

struct ListNode *Insert(struct ListNode *head, int value, int pos)
{
    struct ListNode *temp,*curr;
    curr=head;
    int k=1;
    temp=(struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    if(pos==1)
    {
        temp->data=value;
        if(head==NULL)
        {
            temp->next=NULL;
            head=temp;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next=head;
            head=temp;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while((curr!=NULL) && (k<pos))
        {
            k++;
            curr=curr->next;
        }
        temp->data=value;
        temp->next=curr->next;
        curr->next=temp;

    }
    return head;
}
void printList(struct ListNode *head)
{
    struct ListNode *temp;
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d",temp->data);
        printf(" ");
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
int main
{
    struct ListNode *head=NULL;
    //head = NULL;
    head=Insert(head,10,1);
    //Insert(head,11,2);
    printList(head);

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to return the head of the new linked list after the insertion. I don't know where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: *However, it is failing with compilation error.* Please show the compilation error.

Comment: It doesn't look like ListLength returns a value at all

Comment: In your `printList()`, you are not incrementing `temp` to point to the next node after each print

Comment: `main` is a function, so it needs the ( and ).  I.E. `int main( void )`

Comment: strongly suggest moving this line: `struct ListNode *head=NULL;` inside the body of the `main()` function OR do not pass `head` to each of the sub functions.

Comment: also, your `printList()` takes arguments, you're not passing the head of the list when you're calling it

Comment: regarding: `printList();` in the `main()` function.  The `printList()` function signature has a parameter, a pointer to the 'head' of the list. So the line should be: `printList( head );`

Comment: the signature for the function: `ListLength()` says there is a returned type of `int`.  But the function fails to have a return statement..  Suggest the last line in the function be: `return count;`

Comment: the function: `printList()` never steps the pointer `temp` through the linked list.  Suggest the last line in the `while()` loop be: `temp = temp->next;`

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, 1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  So Casting just clutters the code, making the code more difficult to understand, debug.  Suggest removing the cast.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the function: `Insert()` is trying to change where the 'head' points.  To do that, the passed parameter needs to be the address of 'head', not the contents of 'head'

Comment: in function: `Insert()`, when trying to insert other than at position 1 in the linked list,  If the `while()` loop encounters the end of the list (I.E. `curr` contains NULL) then these statements: `temp->next=curr->next;` and `curr->next=temp;` both have undefined behavior because `curr` contains NULL

Comment: @user3629249 I have edited the code, still facing the error. Why am I not able to return the linked list. I don't know where am I going wrong.

Comment: The error is [Error] expected primary-expression before 'struct'

Comment: Obviously, the code is not edited correctly,  To start, this statement: `int main` is not correct.  Please post the new code (after a 'EDIT' flag).   Remember, A bunch of problems with your posted code were discussed in the comments.  Any/all of those problems need to be addressed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(i) Firstly, include `int main(void)` as mentioned in the comments.

(ii) Next, with your current code, when you try printing the list, you are going to be in an infinite loop and get a stack overflow.

To avoid this, increment the `temp` to point to the next node after each print.

So your print function should look like:

```
void printList(struct ListNode *head)
{
    struct ListNode *temp;
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d",temp->data);
        printf(" ");
        temp=temp->next; // this line is required
    }
}
```

(iii) And in your main function, call the `printList` with an argument, that is the head of the node like this:

```
printList(head);
```

(iv) And don't forget to return the `count` in your finding the length of the list function. Add the return statement at the end of your `ListLength` function:

```
return count;
```

(v) Your current code does not handle a case when `head` is NULL, and user wants to insert at a position greater than 1. Or more generally, when a user wants to insert at a position that is greater than the current list's length.

While you trust such an input would not be given, always handle such exceptions (you would probably get a `SEGMENTATION FAULT` here when trying to access memory of null nodes).

To handle this, you can add a check at the start of the `Insert` function like,

```
int lenList = ListLength(head);
if (lenList < pos)
    {
        printf("Please provide a position less than %d to insert", lenList);
        return 0; // don't proceed with inserting node with NULL pointers
    }
```

Comment: i have edited all still facing the issue. Not able to return the linked list

Comment: also, you have not added `int main(void)` in your main function, fix that too

Comment: tell me the **line number** on which you are getting the error after changing the above, because when I run it, I am getting the print of the list after node is successfully inserted (using the same code)

Comment: also, what compiler are you using? Are you sure you are compiling it as C code and not C++? Do tell me the compiler version and the command you are using to compile.

Comment: I am using Dev CPP, it should compile

Comment: aha.. you should compile with a C compiler, your code is not C++

Comment: Use a C compiler and compile with it, and the error will not be thrown, let me know if this fixed it

Comment: That's great! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score -1):

If head is declared global you don't have to return it. (Sorry, my answer is short)